# React JS mapping / displaying elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, react-props

so I'm trying to pass the player array as props to the App component then use mapping to iterate over initialPlayers and return a player component for each object in the array. Please check the below image.

This is the App.js page.
ReactDOM.render is in index.js.

I receive this error:[image]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialPlayers' of undefined

Any good and quick advice please?

Thank you

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
}

render() {

    const players = [

        { name: "Dex",
            score: 33
        },
        {
            name: "Rocko",
            score: 61
        },
        {
            name: "Lance",
            score: 29
        },
        {
            name: "Zane",
            score: 42
        },

    ];


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App players />,
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You are passing one of the props 'players' to the App Component but not initialPlayers.

Debug in the App Component using 'console.log('props are ', props). So you will come to know what are available in the props of App Component.

Comment: 'console.log('props are ', props) produces an error saying props is not defined

Comment: Trying passing as <App players={players} /> and check console.log('props are ', props)

Comment: I done it and received this: 'props' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 1):

Hı ,

you pass as props is name  `players`  and why do you try to call `initialPlayers` ?

try this :

```
props.players.map
```

Comment: hey, when I do props.players.map: TypeError: Cannot read property 'players' of undefined.

Comment: console.log(players) does return the array though

Answer (score 0):

Try by modifying like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App players={players} />,
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In the way you wrote the code, *players* will be evaluated like an attribute instead of prop.

Furthermore, I suggest you to check your prop.initialPlayers before to iterate a map because it could be undefined (in your case you're having these error because of naming -> it should be **players** instead of *initialPlayer* or vice-versa) so, for example, you could write something like:

```
{(props.players || []).map(etc.)}
```